# Discord.JS: Listening for kicks

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am building a server protection feature. I want to listen for kicks on guilds. I know listening for ban but I could not find the event for kick. Does kick have an event? If not, is there a way to listen for kicks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your comment on renato's was correct, a quick fix for this would be to check the times for the audit log and the join:

```js
if (kickLog.createdAt < member.joinedAt) { 
    return console.log(`${member.user.tag} left the guild, most likely of their own will.`);
}
```

Full code:

```js
client.on('guildMemberRemove', async member => {
    const fetchedLogs = await member.guild.fetchAuditLogs({
        limit: 1,
        type: 'MEMBER_KICK',
    });
    // Since we only have 1 audit log entry in this collection, we can simply grab the first one
    const kickLog = fetchedLogs.entries.first();

    // Let's perform a sanity check here and make sure we got *something*
    if (!kickLog) return console.log(`${member.user.tag} left the guild, most likely of their own will.`);

    // We now grab the user object of the person who kicked our member
    // Let us also grab the target of this action to double check things
    const { executor, target } = kickLog;

    if (kickLog.createdAt < member.joinedAt) { 
        return console.log(`${member.user.tag} left the guild, most likely of their own will.`);
    }

    // And now we can update our output with a bit more information
    // We will also run a check to make sure the log we got was for the same kicked member
    if (target.id === member.id) {
        console.log(`${member.user.tag} left the guild; kicked by ${executor.tag}?`);
    } else {
        console.log(`${member.user.tag} left the guild, audit log fetch was inconclusive.`);
    }
});
```

Comment: That's actually smart. I did not think about `joinedAt` feature. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can find help about kicks event in discord.js official wiki.
Link : [**Link**](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/audit-logs.html#who-kicked-a-user)

The event is: `guildMemberRemove`

This is an example taken from https://discordjs.guide (you can find this clicking the [**Link**](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/audit-logs.html#who-kicked-a-user)) :

```js
client.on('guildMemberRemove', async member => {
    const fetchedLogs = await member.guild.fetchAuditLogs({
        limit: 1,
        type: 'MEMBER_KICK',
    });
    // Since we only have 1 audit log entry in this collection, we can simply grab the first one
    const kickLog = fetchedLogs.entries.first();

    // Let's perform a sanity check here and make sure we got *something*
    if (!kickLog) return console.log(`${member.user.tag} left the guild, most likely of their own will.`);

    // We now grab the user object of the person who kicked our member
    // Let us also grab the target of this action to double check things
    const { executor, target } = kickLog;

    // And now we can update our output with a bit more information
    // We will also run a check to make sure the log we got was for the same kicked member
    if (target.id === member.id) {
        console.log(`${member.user.tag} left the guild; kicked by ${executor.tag}?`);
    } else {
        console.log(`${member.user.tag} left the guild, audit log fetch was inconclusive.`);
    }
});
```

This isn't my code. I copy-pasted this code from discordjs.guide.
Do you need a list of events?

[**Here**](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client) you can find the list. (Source: https://discord.js.org/ and https://discordjs.guide)

Comment: I thought about this way but if the member gets kicked then joins and leaves, I think it will say "member was kicked by ..." again. Because audit log is still there.